# How to build an explicit polyhedral representation of $P_n$

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra, linearization

I am having difficulty with the following question.
Let $P_n = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \; : \; |x_i| \leq 1, i\leq n, \sum_i |x_i| \leq 2 \}$.
Build an explicit polyhedral representation of $P_n$ that is linear. That is, a representation of form
$P_n = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \exists u\in\mathbb{R}^m \text{ s.t. } Ax + Bu \leq c \}$, where $dim(u)$ and $dim(c)$ are linear in $n$ (also $A, B, c, m$ can depend on $n$).

I have a lot of difficulty with questions asking to building explicit polyhedral representations in general. I think I would see how to do these types of questions in general if I saw how specifically to build a polyhedral representation in this case.

Comment: What kind(s) of objects are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be? $c$ is a real number?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, and $c$ is a real vector.

Comment: @Rob, OK, then what's the meaning of $Ax+Bu\le c$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let $d=\dim(c)$.  Then we have matrix-vector multiplication $A_{d \times n} x_{n \times 1} + B_{d \times m} u_{m \times 1} \le c_{d \times 1}$.  That is, $d$ linear inequality constraints with variables $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @Rob, OK, so it means each component of the vector on the left is no greater than the corresponding component of the vector on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you want to linearize the absolute values.  Introduce variable $u_i$ to represent $|x_i|$.  The desired linear constraints in $x$ and $u$ are
\begin{align}
 x_i - u_i &\le 0 \tag1 \\
-x_i - u_i &\le 0 \tag2 \\
u_i &\le 1 \tag3 \\
\sum_i u_i &\le 2 \tag4
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ enforce $|x_i| \le u_i$.  Constraint $(3)$ enforces $|x_i| \le 1$.  Constraint $(4)$ enforces $\sum_i |x_i| \le 2$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. One question: When one is trying to create a polyhedral representation, does one usually make the "$u$" stand in for a "special function" (like the absolute value function)?

Comment: Yes, the additional variables often represent some nonlinear function of the original variables.  Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.